# Combinatorial description of hard Lefschetz for toric manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a toric variety which is compact and smooth (feel free to correct me if I’m missing adjectives), and let $\Sigma$ be the corresponding fan. The ordinary cohomology ring $H^*(X)$ has a combinatorial description as follows. Take the torus action of $T$ on $X$. Then $X$ has finitely many $T$-invariant divisors $X_1,...,X_m$. The equivariant cohomology $H^*_T(X)$ is given by the Stanley-Reisner ring $\mathbb{Z}[\tau_1,...,\tau_m]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $\{\prod_{j \in J}\tau_j: \cap_{j \in J}X_j =\emptyset\}$. Finally, $H^*(X)$ is given by $H^*_T(X)/J$, where $J$ is a certain ideal generated by linear combinations of the $\tau_i$, dictated by the fan $\Sigma$.

Now, by virtue of being a nonsingular projective variety, $X$ satisfies hard Lefschetz.

> Is there a nice combinatorial description of hard Lefschetz from this point of view? Ideally, one that describes where each $\tau_i$ is sent.

I suspect that either this is easy or it has already been studied, but after googling nothing came up. References are welcome!

Comment: This to me seems like a question better asked on MO

Comment: Thanks for the advice, fo you know if crossposting is allowed?

Comment: I’m pretty sure yes, you can just let them know it’s cross-posted and provide a link to the original question

Comment: Crossposted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459555/combinatorial-description-of-hard-lefschetz-for-toric-manifolds